# How did lord Rama reach Rameshwaram?

Tags: rama

How did Lord Rama arrive to Rameshwaram island? There was no way to reach Rameshwaram then except going on a boat. Also with his huge army he can't go to Rameshwaram with boat.

Comment: Ramayana happened thousand of years ago then the sea level must have been lower than the existing levels. Almost very short span after Ice age so may be there is no melting of polar ice caps (Just an scientific speculation) at that time Rameshwaram should have been connected to the main land or less currents bring less water levels.